# Web site references a console app which uses NHibernate to talk to database

Tags: c#, nhibernate, web-applications

I've written a console app which basically downloads an XML file, manipulates it and puts the data into a database. This app uses *NHibernate* and *MindScapes* NHibernate designer tool. Which works fine when I run it as a stand alone thing.

Now I want to create an MVC website and when a certain button is clicked on that website, I want it to trigger the console app to download the appropriate xml file and do its thing.

I get an error:

> Could not find file
>   'C:\Dev\WagerWatcher\WagerWatcherWeb\bin\hibernate.cfg.xml'.":"C:\Dev\WagerWatcher\WagerWatcherWeb\bin\hibernate.cfg.xml

`WagerWatcherWeb` is the website, So I think it's looking in the *WagerWatcherWeb* project for a file which is actually located in the '`WagerWatcher`' project.

Is it as simple as changing an app.config file somewhere to redirect to the actual file? and if so, where abouts? I can't fins it to save myself,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place (copy) the configuration file (used in your console app) to deployed *web-app* folder. Read: [3.8. XML Configuration File](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#configuration-xmlconfig)

> An alternative approach is to specify a full configuration in a file named hibernate.cfg.xml. This file can be used as a replacement for the `<nhibernate>` or `<hibernate-configuration>` sections of the application configuration file.

While the web application is the "run-time" *(just calling the API of your console application)* it must be provided with all configuration. Even for referenced libraries...

Comment: Thanks man, that worked like a charm.... I can't up vote though, I need some reputation.
Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Great to hear that. Good look with NHibernate ;)